# GRIDFS driver and sample tutorial

Tags: android, mongodb, gridfs

Is there a link on where to download GRIDFS driver for Android and a sample tutorial.I appreciate it.

Comment: I think what you need to appreciate is a little bit of advise saying **do not attempt to connect to a database from a remote client**. Use a REST API or some other service middleman as the intermediary here. Don't ever think a web client is safe to talk to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Gridfs is used by MongoDb to store large file in small chunks in database.

You don't have a separate .jar file for gridfs in android. It is already included in Mongo.jar. Import Mongo.jar in your project and you will have access to it.

Comment: that is all I need to know. Now, will look for sample codes and tutorials.

Comment: @padlanau for basic operation u can have a look at http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/07/23/java-mongodb-getsave-image-using-gridfs-apis/

Comment: @padlanau for detailed tutorials you can have a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: yes the answer was accepted. After importing mongo.jar, I was able to create an object and play around. –  padlanau